# Build multiple examples with cmake

Tags: cmake

My project uses the same core code, and i want to build the following structure

```
project
|
| - core_code
| - cmake 
| - CMakeLists.txt
| - example1
|     |
|     |- example1.cc
|     |- build
|
| - example2
|     |
|     |- example2.cc
|     |- build
```

I would like cmake to create targets in the build subdirectories for each example. So after I run `cmake` from `projects` directory then build, the structure should look like this:

```
project
    |
    | - core
    | - cmake 
    | - CMakeLists.txt
    | - example1
    |     |
    |     |- example1.cc
    |     |- build
    |          |- Makefile
    |          |- example1
    |
    | - example2
    |     |
    |     |- example2.cc
    |     |- build
    |          |- Makefile
    |          |- example2
```

What should I do in `project/CMakeLists.txt`?

Answer (score 4):

If you structure your project as follows:

```
project
    |
    |- CMakeLists.txt
    |- core
    |    |
    |    |- core.cc
    |    |- core.h
    |    |- CMakeLists.txt
    |
    |- example1
    |    |
    |    |- example1.cc
    |    |- CMakeLists.txt
    |
    |- example2
         |
         |- example2.cc
         |- CMakeLists.txt
```

Your `project/CMakeLists.txt` file just includes the other cmakelists files

**`project/CMakeLists.txt`:**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)
project (project CXX C)

add_subdirectory(core)
add_subdirectory(example1)
add_subdirectory(example2)
```

Your `core/CMakeLists.txt` file builds the core targets

**`project/core/CMakeLists.txt`:**

```
add_library(core core.cc)
target_include_directories(core PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Your `exampleN/CMakeLists.txt` file builds the example targets

**`project/example1/CMakeLists.txt`:**

```
add_executable(example1 example.cc)
target_link_libraries(example1 core)
```

When you generate the build files, cmake mimics your directory structure in the build directory, so running the following commands would result in the below directory structure:

```
$ cd project
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
```

The resulting directory structure would look as follows:

```
project
    |
    |- CMakeLists.txt
    |- core
    |    |
    |    |- core.cc
    |    |- core.h
    |    |- CMakeLists.txt
    |
    |- example1
    |    |
    |    |- example1.cc
    |    |- CMakeLists.txt
    |
    |- example2
    |    |
    |    |- example2.cc
    |    |- CMakeLists.txt
    |                                  
    |- build
         |
         |- Makefile
         |- core
         |     |- Makefile
         |
         |- example1
         |     |- Makefile
         |     |- example1
         |
         |- example2
               |- Makefile
               |- example2
```

Now if you only want to build `example2` for example, you can execute the following:

```
$ cd project/build/example2
$ make
```

The benefit of this is that it doesn't pollute your source tree with build files. If you want to blow away the build directory, you only need to delete one directory

```
$ rm -r project/build
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have *additional* `CMakeLists.txt` somewhere, e.g. at `cmake/example/CMakeLists.txt` with content like:

```
add_executable(${EXAMPLE_NAME} ${EXAMPLE_DIR}/${EXAMPLE_NAME}.cc)
```

you may call it from `project/CMakeLists.txt` with:

```
# Build the first example in the 'example1/build' subdirectory
set(EXAMPLE_NAME example1)
set(EXAMPLE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/example1)
add_subdirectory(cmake/example ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/example1/build)
# Build the second example in the 'example2/build' subdirectory
set(EXAMPLE_NAME example2)
set(EXAMPLE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/example2)
add_subdirectory(cmake/example ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/example2/build)
```

Note, that CMake generates Makefile's only in the *build directory*, and the only way to change build directory is `add_subdirectory()` call. So you cannot get `Makefile` not in the top-level directory without additional `CMakeLists.txt`. But you may use single additional `CMakeLists.txt` for multiple build directories.

---

To be precise, you **may** use top-level `CMakeLists.txt` for examples too, but you need to make it "reentrant", which seems ugly for me.